# Is it closed questions cleanup day?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I can't find some closed questions, have they been purged? I couldn't find them in my favorites list either.

Some of them were duplicates, but were really useful.

Comment: Your language is slightly off...

Comment: @Tradition: I know, I'm sorry...

Comment: I thought every day was closed questions cleanup day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may have been deleted, as closed questions are often deleted within a few days. Users with greater than 10,000 reputation can view deleted questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might wondering following question, which is deleted few hours ago(can only see by 10k+ users now)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714133/i-would-like-to-learn-c-what-is-the-first-step-closed

I am not sure it should be deleted or not.

Comment: it's exactly the question that I was looking for. So I just need other 9512 points to view my deleted question ?

Comment: @Cesar, that's right.